# Access input name attribute using template literals (React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hook-form

I'm having some problem to use errors (object provided by React Hook Form) to show a validation message (when a required input field is empty) for the input fields.

```
{
  inputs.map((name) => (
    <div key={name}>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "3px" }}>
        <input
          name={`Chamfer Set.${name}`}
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </div>
      {errors[`Chamfer Set.${name}`] && (
        <span>Please enter a value for {name}.</span>
      )}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Basically I have to link **errors** to the **input name attribute**, which in this case I'm using template literals. But it is not working and I guess it is something related to the literals, but I'm not very into it. Do you guys have any idea?

If I use console.log(errors), I have the following structure:

[image]

Comment: what is the value in name variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the error property just replace:

```
errors[`Chamfer Set.${name}`]
```

By:

```
errors["Chamfer Set"] && errors["Chamfer Set"][`${name}`]
```

Comment: Not working, I'm having TypeError: Cannot read property 'l' of undefined :(

Comment: @Polalas this is because the errors could be empty. I edited to consider this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As @Micheal mentioned, Try

```
{
  inputs.map((name) => (
    <div key={name}>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "3px" }}>
        <input
          name={`Chamfer Set.${name}`}
          ref={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </div>
      {errors[`Chamfer Set`][`${name}`] && (
        <span>Please enter a value for {name}.</span>
      )}
    </div>
  ));
}
```